# how to restrict more than 1 ampersand consecutively in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string that should contain `one name` then `&` and then `second name`.
and two consecutive `&` should not occur. Also last character should not be `&`.

i have tried following code but this is not working

```
System.out.println("45345&&345".matches("(^(?!&)(?!.*&&)[0-9&]+(?<!&))$"));
```

regex is as  `(^(?!&)(?!.*&&)[0-9&]+(?<!&))$`

but its not working!!
Can you please help me.

Comment: @ndn i have tried this but its also not working

Comment: It matches lines as long as they have only one `&` in them and don't start or end with that `&`. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: ok i got your point @ndn let me check once

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show some examples of matching and non-matching strings.

Comment: @ndn wait for 3 minutes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one `&` on line and doesn't start or end with `&`:

```
^[^&]+&[^&]+$
```

Can contain multiple `&`, but not consecutive ones and doesn't start or end with `&`:

```
^(?:[^&]+&)+[^&]+$
```

Comment: Please check the second regular expression against `abc&def&&ghi&jkl`. The clause `(?:[^&]*&)+` allows zero of the `[^&]` leading to the unwanted match. I think `^(?:[^&]+&)+[^&]+$` does the job.

Answer (score 3):

```
String sa = "santanu&sahoo&";
System.out.println(!sa.contains("&&")?sa.matches(".*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(&)([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*&$"):"False");
```